# Nuget Ignores Default Project

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, nuget

For some reason Nuget ignores the default project I select from the drop down and always installs packages into my startup web project. I have a utility project, specifically for things like library dependencies and want Nuget to install packages there, but it always goes for the web project.

EDIT:

I eventually figured this out. It turns out that the solution file was under one particular projects directory. This was not how I normally create a solution, but I didn't create this originally so it didn't occur to me that this was the cause.

Answer (score 1):

Try using command with project name

```
PM> Install-Package EntityFramework -ProjectName DataProvider
```

or Just right click on the Solution and select Manage NuGet Packages.
when you install it allows selecting the set of projects to install the package into.

Comment: Nope! I removed all signs of nuget packages from my project, ran a command based on your example and even though it will add the correct references to the project I specified, it downloads the files to the web project. I even made my utility project the default startup project, and it still downloads to the web app. Frustrating!